# grep only specific section of file; determine OS X system version in a shell script

Tags: string, macos, bash, grep, applescript

To find the current version of OS X a user is running from, the **SystemVersion.plist** file will show this. How would I use the `grep` command to find just the version number and return it?

For example:

```
cat /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

will produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
    <key>ProductBuildVersion</key>
    <string>13A598</string>
    <key>ProductCopyright</key>
    <string>1983-2013 Apple Inc.</string>
    <key>ProductName</key>
    <string>Mac OS X</string>
    <key>ProductUserVisibleVersion</key>
    <string>10.9</string>
    <key>ProductVersion</key>
    <string>10.9</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So, in due course I would run:

```
cat /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist | grep 10.9
```

and this would return:

```
    <string>10.9</string>
    <string>10.9</string>
```

The second `<string>10.9</string>` comes from the `<key>ProductUserVisibleVersion</key>` key.  How would I manipulate the grep command so it searches for and **ONLY** returns the 10.9 *only* from here? I know that I used my `grep` in the example to find specifically the *10.9* response, but I want to show whatever comes up between `<string>` and `</string>`.

I will be incorporating this into a test, which would hopefully return the **visible** OS X version and check it with an **if / else** command and then run call functions accordingly.

I am open to a `bash` script solution, as then I can also implement that into other options. AppleScript as an alternative solution would be good to know too.

Comment: @DigiMonk I use a combination of AppleScript and bash to do certain tasks. Bash is what I am after primarily, and I tagged the question with "bash" and "grep" firstly, I added "AppleScript" later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following doesn't address the general grep-related question, but solves your specific problem succinctly:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print :ProductUserVisibleVersion' /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

Alternative, AppleScript-based solution:

```
osascript -e 'system version of (system info)'
```

Comment: I'm awarding the correct answer not to you because of what @DigiMonk said, but because you've managed to answer both the [tag:AppleScript] and [tag:bash] alternatives. I've derived much from asking this question

Comment: Thanks, @DanijelJ (you haven't accepted it yet, though). Since the answers now provide simple solutions for both getting the OS X version *and* useful general parsing techniques, would you mind revising the question title to reflect that (and perhaps adding a little preface to the question body)?

Answer (score 3):

Apple is gradually converting their plist files in OS X from XML to binary format, so I'd recommend using something that knows how to read both: either `defaults` or `PlistBuddy`.

```
$ defaults read /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion ProductUserVisibleVersion
10.8.5
$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :ProductUserVisibleVersion" /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist 
10.8.5
```

(I'm running 10.8.5, obviously, but the same commands should work with 10.9 or 10.7, or...)

Answer (score 3):

Simple approach.

```
awk '/ProductUserVisibleVersion/ {getline;print}' /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
<string>10.9</string>
```

Or just the value

```
awk -F"<|>" '/ProductUserVisibleVersion/ {getline;print $3}' /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
10.9
```

Comment: This is such an underrated answer. I was trying to find similar answer for Info.plist. Though this would be a very obvious thing answered /  explained manny times everywhere since plist is so commonly used in iOS / macOS development. But yours is the first precise useful 'shell' answer (and not using PlistBuddy or anything macOS only #$*&^). Thank you.

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke This is an old answer.  Since I have later found that `getline` is full of pitfall and should be avoided, you could use this instead.  `awk -F"<|>" 'f {print $3;f=0} /ProductUserVisibleVersion/ {f=1}' filename`  It will search for text, if found set flag f.  If flag f is true (the next line), print value and set flag f to 0.

Comment: Thank you. You can edit your answer with this update.

Answer (score 2):

100% external Bash:

```
grep -A2  '<key>ProductUserVisibleVersion</key>' | grep '<string>' |cut -d\> -f2 |cut -d\< -f1
```

or 100% internal Bash:

```
while read LINE
do
    if [ "$LINE" = "<key>ProductUserVisibleVersion</key>" ]
    then   
        read LINE
        LINE=${LINE#*>}
        echo ${LINE%<*}
        exit
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `xml` parser. Here you have an example with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and its `XML::Twig` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'plist/dict/string' => sub {
            my $prev = $_->prev_sibling('key');
            return unless defined $prev;
            if ( $prev->tag eq 'key' and 
                 $prev->text_only eq 'ProductUserVisibleVersion' ) {
                printf "%s\n", $_->text_only;
                exit 0;
            }   
        },  
    },  
)->parsefile( shift );
```

You can run it like:

```
perl script.pl /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

That yields:

```
10.9
```

Comment: I have never used Perl because I do not know how to. I am going to pocket this answer for later as it may come handy when I delve in to Perl sometime in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use grep and sed:

```
$ grep -e "<string>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+</string>" | sed -n -e 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/\1/p'
```

I havent tested but its something similar!

Comment: Thank you for showing me an example using `sed`. I tried to do this myself, but failed miserably. I will be able to keep this example and build on it in future projects.